# partial wedge shape on html5 canvas

Tags: html, canvas

I want to draw this shape on html5 canvas. Basically these are arcs joined together to form a closed shape object. I don't mind if KineticJs is used to achieve this.

[image]

I'm not getting anything on Google regarding this. Could you please help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Your partial wedge polygon can be made using a Path:**

A Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/5d2bX/

[image]

The path consists of:

- start drawing the wedge on top-left
- a top arc sweeping left to right
- a line moving down on the right
- a bottom arc sweeping right to left
- a closePath command that will automatically draw the line from bottom-left to top-left

Here's what that looks like in code:

```
// canvas references
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

// the centerpoint of the partial wedge
var cx=150;
var cy=150;

// the inside and outside radii
var insideRadius=60;
var outsideRadius=100;

// the beginning and ending angles 
var beginningAngle=Math.PI*5/4;
var endingAngle=Math.PI*7/4;

// use trigonometry to calculate the starting point
// of the bottom leftward sweeping arc
var x=cx+insideRadius*Math.cos(endingAngle);
var y=cy+insideRadius*Math.sin(endingAngle);

// set the path style
ctx.strokeStyle="black";
ctx.fillStyle="red";
ctx.lineWidth=2;

// begin the path

ctx.beginPath();

// top-arc: sweeping from top-left to top-right

ctx.arc(cx,cy,outsideRadius,beginningAngle,endingAngle);

// right-line: from the end of top-arc to the right of bottom-arc

ctx.lineTo(x,y);

// bottom-arc: sweeping from bottom-right to bottom left
// (Note: the true on the end causes the arc to sweep right to left

ctx.arc(cx,cy,insideRadius,endingAngle,beginningAngle,true);

// left-line: closes the path between the
// bottom-left and top left arcs.

ctx.closePath();

// fill & stroke the path
ctx.fill();
ctx.stroke();
```

Comment: Thanks, I will accept your answer but I was able to do it with a bit simpler approach, without much trigonometric calculations as your did. See my fork on your demo http://jsfiddle.net/y3Bk4/1/